# Are file formats independent of endian of system?

Tags: operating-system, endianness, internals

There are many common file formats, for example jpeg images.

Suppose a jpeg image exists on two systems, one using big endian and the other small endian.

Will the saveed jpeg files look different?

In other words, if we have the images saved in a contiguous area of memory say starting from byte 0, will the images be the same?

Comment: You have to read the spec for the particular file format you are interested in.  Most common file formats specify endianness and the like so that they can work the same on all systems, but there are exceptions.  For instance Berkeley DB files come in both big- and little-endian versions; their software will handle both versions on any system, but any given system creating a new file will probably use its native byte order.